# Error while creating directories: Invalid argument

Tags: android, opencv

I imported OpenCV 2.4.11 into my eclipse project and it showed me this error. "OpenCV Library - 2.4.11] aidl.exe E 12720 13160 io_delegate.cpp:102] Error while creating directories: Invalid argument". Does anyone know how I can resolve this. Thanks in advance.